# What is the significance of the sketch of Lenin on Clouseau's apartment wall in The Return of the Pink Panther?

Tags: props, the-return-of-the-pink-panther

I was recently re-watching *The Return of the Pink Panther* when I noticed a sketch of Lenin on the wall of Clouseau's apartment (early in the film, about 10 minutes, I think). Does anyone know why it's there? Is it just a sight gag? Was the idea from Peter Sellers? Blake Edwards?

I've seen all the Peter Sellers Pink Panther Movies, and I don't remember seeing this or other sketches of Lenin before. Probably I just missed it, as when earlier watching this film. Has anyone noticed a Lenin sketch in other Pink Panther movies?

Also, I wasn't able to find the source of that particular sketch, although it looks familiar. What is its source, or did Edwards or Sellers draw it?